# How to covert mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox in which date is in format mm/dd/yyyy. I want to convert it from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in asp.net with vb to a DateTime variable.

Comment: You need to be a little bit more specific. Do you have that data in a DateTime variable? In a string? Do you need to output to the Console, to Windows Forms, to a WebPage?

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/21/2008", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")
```

Update: Given that you want to have a DateTime in the end, you can just parse the original format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/21/2008", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The date formats are of use only when presenting the date as a string (internally the date does not have a format; it's just a number). If you want to store it in a DateTime all you need to bother about is to interpret the input correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a DateTime object you convert can like this:

```
yourDateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```